# Command line Ant not recognised

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, ant

** Edit ** I have summarized the solutions I found to this problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979209/environment-variable-errors-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) post.

I am installing Android into Eclipse which I have been using for Java for 2 years. As part of this I have installed Ant and also upgraded to JDK1.7.0

Per the [Cordova get started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), I now run command line tests by typing java to see if it is recognized, then ant.

- java is recognized (thanks to Nikolay Ivanov's help in a previous question)
- ant fails to recognise anything

I have ANT_HOME set to "c:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4"
My PATH variable includes "%ANT_HOME%\lib".
I have also tried %ANT_HOME%\bin and %ANT_HOME%.
The ant.jar file is in c:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib

But "ant" on the command line is still un-recognised.

FWIW, I now restart my command line interface every time I make a change in my environmental variables...

** Edit, I have removed %ANT_HOME%\bin from my build path and replaced it with "C:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin".

I now have a new error "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed"

Comment: did you restart your system after the  settings? some times reboot can help you

Comment: @Festus No I haven't. I'll report back in a few minutes...

Comment: @Festus No effect, ant is still not recognised. Path is set to %ANT_HOME%\bin and echo %ANT_HOME% generates "C:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4".

Comment: try to download a new ant may be there is bug in your actual version

Comment: No change. And I restarted my PC as well. I just tried putting the full name in the PATH variable "C:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin" and that created a new error message, "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed"

Comment: for what do you need to install ant for android?

Comment: No idea, I'm following instructions given by Apache Cordova. As per the get started guide I link to above. I'm guessing the reasons why I need it will become clear once I move on from installing to reading tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path should include %ANT_HOME%\bin but not %ANT_HOME%\lib.

Comment: As mentioned, I tried that. And I've just tried it again, just in case... That does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: it gives...  'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: then type PATH and check if bin folder from ant is there

Comment: Yes, and I've changed my PATH to take the %ANT_HOME% out of the equation. I have "C:\Developer\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin" and it is now placed at the start of the PATH variable. As I mentioned to Festus, I do have a new error though (from changing the PATH variable, not re-ordering the PATH), a "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed" error.

Comment: when you invoke ant, build.xml should be in current folder. is it there?

Comment: No. But, I just checked and found "ant -version" gives me a version number. I'm picking then that ant is working, just complaining (& that this is the direction you are heading in). So I'll consider this question resolved, I've still got issues, but at least I'm a step closer. Ta for your help.